# How do you redirect URLs with a query string with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect, litespeed

I want to redirect pages like :

```
example.com/fr/opportunites/?sector_cat=bourses-detudes&ajax_filter=true
```

To

```
example.com/fr/bourses-detudes/
```

the second page is a post type page created with WordPress

Is there any possibility to do that with htacees in litespeed server ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In order to match against the query string part of the URL you need to use mod_rewrite with a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that specifically checks the query string. Other directives only check against the URL-path (which naturally excludes the query string).

So, from your example, to redirect from `/fr/opportunites/?sector_cat=<value>&ajax_filter=true` to `/fr/<value>/` you would need to use something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file *before* the existing WordPress directives.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sector_cat=([^&]+)&ajax_filter=true$
RewriteRule ^fr/opportunites/$ /fr/%1/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The URL parameters (`sector_cat` and `ajax_filter`) must match in the order stated and no other URL params are permitted. The value of the `sector_cat` parameter must also be non-empty, otherwise it matches any characters except for `&`.

The `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* contains the captured subpattern from the query string (ie. the `sector_cat` parameter value).

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is necessary in order to remove the original query string from the redirected response.

There is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* when used in `.htaccess`. So, `^fr/` matches `/fr/` at the start of the URL-path.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect (if that is the intention) once you have confirmed it works as intended.